# Multiple form submits in body tag

Tags: submit, form-submit, onload

Although I have found a few questions related to this, none has quite addressed my specific situation. I have a PHP script that I want to call other scripts, without clicking. I have used this structure with success:

```
 <body onload="form1.submit()">
 <?php
 .
 .
 .
 if ($value=="yes"){
 print<<<HERE
 <form method="post" id="form1" action="nextapp.php">
 <input="hidden" name="data" value="some data">
 </form>
 HERE
 }
 else
 .
 .
 .
```

The above works perfectly. However, what if I want to be able to react to two different forms? This does NOT work:

```
 <body onload="form1.submit(); form2.submit()">
```

nor does

```
 <body onload="form1.submit()" onload="form2.submit()">
```

There were a few other weirder variations I tried that, not surprisingly (due to being so weird), didn't work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.  It appears you are trying to decide whether or not to include a message/form on a page and then automatically branch to a new file after deciding which message is generated.   You can not have to submits in the onload the execution of form1.submit will either take you off the page prohibiting the form2.submit, or the absence of form1 will screw up the javascript execution of form1.submit and likely fail execution the form2.submit().

Comment: If your attempt is to perform a branch on mutually exclusive conditions, use your conditional to build your onload statement in the body statement.   If you are trying to perform 2 or more php files simultaneously, you probably need to try a different method.

Comment: Your idea to use the conditional to build the onload worked perfectly. Not sure why I didn't think of it myself - in any event - THANK YOU!